# Как правильно разделить текст на части?

Tags: php

В тексте (вакансии) есть три основных ключа : Требования, Условия, Обязанности.

вот пример :

```
В строительную компанию, на постоянную работу требуются специалисты по отделке помещений различного назначения.

Требования:

- Опыт работы в сфере ремонтно-строительных услуг (квартиры, офисы, магазины) от 1 года 
- Аккуратность, внимательность, стрессоустойчивость

Обязанности:

- Своевременное, качественное выполнение работ по отделке помещений различного назначения (квартиры, офисы, торговые площади)

Условия:
- График работы 6/1
- Объекты г. Иваново/Ивановская область
```

Эти ключи могут быть в разном положении, некоторые могут отсутствовать, но всегда после них идет описание.

Возможно ли как-то разделить текст на несколько логических частей (нужно в базу по отдельным колонка занести будет в итоге), чтобы более-менее было все логично по тексту  ?

Comment: `стрессоустойчивость` - я даже знать не хочу что именно придётся выслушивать на работе с такими требованиями. Делить текст можно, но какие определения для описания? Текст после кодовых слов через две новые строки и без содержания двух новых строк подряд?

Answer (score 1):

Решение "в лоб":

```
<?php    
$data = preg_split('/(Требования:|Обязанности:|Условия:)/u', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

На выходе получите массив такого вида:

```
array (
  0 => 'В строительную компанию, на постоянную работу требуются специалисты по отделке помещений различного назначения.

',
  1 => 'Требования:',
  2 => '

- Опыт работы в сфере ремонтно-строительных услуг (квартиры, офисы, магазины) от 1 года 
- Аккуратность, внимательность, стрессоустойчивость

',
  3 => 'Обязанности:',
  4 => '

- Своевременное, качественное выполнение работ по отделке помещений различного назначения (квартиры, офисы, торговые площади)

',
  5 => 'Условия:',
  6 => '
- График работы 6/1
- Объекты г. Иваново/Ивановская область',
)
```

Теперь можно ориентируясь на ключевые слова, которые будут отдельными элементами массива, определить идущий за ними и относящийся к ним контент. Понятное дело, что точность разбора в таком варианте - очень относительная.

Answer (score 1):

Можно собрать шаблон для получения слов, за которыми находится двоеточие с последующим описанием, и сохранять совпавшие подстроки по отдельным ячейкам массива. Но так как "ключевые слова" могут располагаться в разных позициях, то привязаться к конкретному элементу результирующего массива не выйдет - понадобится ещё какой-то дальнейший разбор результирующего массива:

```
$str = 'В строительную компанию, на постоянную работу требуются специалисты по отделке помещений различного назначения.

Требования:

- Опыт работы в сфере ремонтно-строительных услуг (квартиры, офисы, магазины) от 1 года 
- Аккуратность, внимательность, стрессоустойчивость

Обязанности:

- Своевременное, качественное выполнение работ по отделке помещений различного назначения (квартиры, офисы, торговые площади)

Условия:

- График работы 6/1
- Объекты г. Иваново/Ивановская область';

$patt = '~\pL+:[\r\n]+^-[\s\w(),./-]+$~um';
preg_match_all($patt, $str, $arr);

var_dump($arr);
```

---

Собственно **готовое решение** будет выглядеть так:

```
$result = [];

preg_replace_callback(
    '~\pL+:[\r\n]+^-[\s\w(),./-]+$~um',
    function($a)use(&$result){
        preg_match('~(\pL+):~u', $a[0], $key);
        $result[$key[1]] = str_replace($key[0], '', $a[0]);
    },
    $str
);
```

Доступ к необходимым элементам можно получить по ключам:

`echo $result['Обязанности'];`